# C++: How to restrict an operator overload to class scope?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a class `A` that performs elementwise `std::pair` addition often. For convenience, I want to overload `operator+` for two `std::pair`s like so:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> operator+(std::pair<T, U> left, std::pair<T, U> right)
{
    return {left.first + right.first, left.second + right.second};
}
```

But, I don't want to introduce this overload outside the scope of `A`, since it's really only useful inside `A`. So I might do something like:

```
class A
{
    // ...
    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::pair<T, U> operator+(std::pair<T, U> left, std::pair<T, U> right)
    {
        return {left.first + right.first, left.second + right.second};
    }
    // ...
};
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since to C++ this looks like a member operator overload of the `+` operator on `A` with two additional arguments (fails to compile since `operator+` only expects one argument as a member overload).

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You can make it a static member function of `A`, although you have to give up on using the name `operator+`. [Like so](https://godbolt.org/z/7fbs6ojb9)

Comment: Don't do it as an operator function - the problems you've having are REQUIRED properties of an operator function.   Provide a member function of `A` named `add()` that accepts two `std::pair`s and returns another.   Make it `private` to prevent calling it outside of `A`s member functions or `friend`s.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you follow disciplined programming practices, and you have a translation unit that implements only `A`'s methods and nothing else.

In that case, putting this overload into an [unnamed namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces), at the beginning of `A.cpp` should do the trick:

```
namespace {

    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::pair<T, U> operator+(std::pair<T, U> left, std::pair<T, U> right)
    {
        return {left.first + right.first, left.second + right.second};
    }
}

std::pair<int, char> A::grobthem(const std::pair<int, char> &a, const std::pair<int, char> b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Multiple translation units may use their own definition of the `+` overload, internally, without conflicting with each other; although if they are logically identical this will result in unnecessary code bloat.

Comment: That bloat can be reduced with link time optimization, though.

Comment: Disciplined programmer practices are, all too often, not a given.   Any function or class defined in that source file - not just `A`s member functions - can access the operator.